# codeigniter generating thousands of cache files

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I just upgraded codeigniter and am trying to use its internal page caching for the first time. Problem is, it seems to be generating thousands of cache files.

It created 65,000 in a week, the site at most has 10k pages, of which no more than 2,000 are visited in a month.

It's very simple to use, It's one line just as described in the docs.

`php
public function article($permalink){
  $data['article'] = $this->getArticleByPermalink($permalink);
  $this->output->cache(60*24);
  $this->load->view('article', $data);
}`

I have it set, for its lowest cache time, 24 hours. I've seen the fix of putting them in different folders - but why is that required? Shouldn't it be making one cache file per page and only one when/if that page is visited?

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Could you share some code so we can figure it out?

Comment: I added some code, but there isn't really much. It's basically one line that turns on its use.

Comment: We need to see the part where you call cache and load view at controller and some parts of view like there: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/codeigniter_page_caching.htm

Comment: By the way if your page is not static but dynamic, (*by dynamic I mean HTML changing by the short period of time like hourly because data is changing*) using page caching pointless. Also using `$this->output->delete_cache()` may be the solution on your situation.

Comment: Delete cache will delete the whole cache which isn't what I want here. These pages are static - they're news articles. There's nothing special about the code (I've added a bit more). Maybe a better question is this: how many cache files should I expect per static page? I'd assume that there should be one, replaced each time the cache time expires. But this isn't the case - I can see that there are duplicate files not just by their count, but by greping the titles of the cache files. When are they created is another question. Are they created on a visit or does CI scrape links?